# change yarn global dir - I can not change the yarn global installation folder

Tags: yarnpkg

**Bug**

yarn is not changing its global directory

The following command changes the cache directory. no problem ... thanks Yarn
yarn config set cache-folder c:\yarn\cache

But this command is not changing the global installation dir

```
yarn config set globa-dir c:\yarn\global
```

when i check after running this command:

```
yarn global dir
```

it displays:
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global

Expected behavior
running the command

```
yarn global dir
```

shows c:\yarn\global instead

**Environnement**

- Yarn 1.6.0 Node: 9.10.1 OS: win32 x64

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the line --global-folder "c:\yarn\global" manually into your .yarnrc file.

Look here [#5746](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5746)